# Special characters like ñ á é í ó ú are imported as ??? in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, insert, special-characters

I have been trying to import words with special characters into MySQL via PHP INSERT command and I either get ??? for each special character or everything after it is cut off.

I have read a lot on the Internet buy none of the solutions seems to be working.

So currently `Coruña` from the script, inserts as `Coru???a` in SQL with the code below:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user",'pass','database');
$con->query("SET NAMES 'utf8' ");
$con->query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");

 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tbl_state (id, statecode, statename,country) 
  VALUES (1, 'A Coruña', 'A Coruña', 'ES')");

mysqli_close($con);
```

My page encoding is `content="text/html; charset=utf-8"`.

I have tried with `utf8_general_ci` and `utf8_spanish_ci` collation for both table and column in MySQL but no success.

Any experts who have come to this problem, what could be wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using htmlspecialchars? http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: What is the database collation itself? Have you confirmed the table and column are `utf8_general_ci` by checking in your database client?

Comment: try `utf8_encode` on `A Coruña` or each text that has a special key.. also, what is the collation of your database? is it utf8? (use utf8_encode ONLY if your charset is ISO-8859-1, else try iconv http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php)

Comment: Note: you need to check for connection failures BEFORE you start using the connection. connecting, try to set connection parameters, and THEN checking if the connection is even working is bass-ackwards.

Comment: Don't use `htmlspecialchars()` btw - that's for escaping output, not for storing stuff in the database.

Comment: database, table and column are all in `utf8_general_ci`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so instead of trying to input the data via PHP script, I inserted it directly from phpMyAdmin with an INSERT query.

For the data to output correct in PHP (without squares or question marks) I added this when making the connection:

`$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");`

All worked great!

Thank you for the help and if someone still find the answer on how to do it via PHP script it will be interesting to hear.